# Int(input) linked to a conditional if statement doesn't output correctly, and else statement callback forms an infinite recursion loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, random, conditional-statements

(I'm still new to forum posting, apologies if this is laid out/worded poorly)

Please could you help me solve this. My question is that I'm trying to get the user to input an integer that is valid to a dice, eg, 6, 12, 20 etc. (I only have it set up for D6 and D20's currently) for my dice rolling application that I aim to work like a standalone version to what is used on Roll20.net,

I have two issues:

1.)  When the user picks a valid die, eg 6 or 20, rather than rolling said die, it just returns the number 6 or 20, or any number you type in past the first else failure, eg 12, 76, 9709487. When instead it should post either a 1 or a 2 with the respective print statement as I have randint set to (1,2) testing the print statements.

2.) Trying to callback the pick_dice function for another attempt causes the program to fall into a recursion loop, and trying to use a break statement also causes me to have an error. If a string is attempted as an input a ValueError is thrown up rather than just the else statement. I'm finding this extremely confusing, I'm not even sure if I am using the correct conditionals (I find the python documentation extremely confusing and I cannot find anything on there that makes sense to help me solve my issue).

My Code:

```
import random
from random import randint

d20 = randint(1,2)  #for test purposes rather than (1,20)
d6 = randint(1,2)

str1 = "You rolled a "
str2 = "Uh Oh, Critical Fail"
str3 = "Congrats Critical Hit"

#num = d20
#To select a die - More will be added later e.g. d10, d12, d100
num = int(input("Please pick a valid die: 6 or 20: "))


def roll(d20):
    print(str1, d20)

    if d20 == 1:
        print(str2)    
    elif d20 == 2:
        print(str3)

#roll(d20)

def roll(d6):
    print(str1, d6)

    if d6 == 1:
        print(str2)    
    elif d6 == 2:
        print(str3)

#roll (d6)


def dice():
    if num == d20:
        roll(d20)
    elif num == d6:
        roll(d6)

dice()


def pick_dice():
    print (num)
    if num is 6 or num is 20:
        dice()
    #elif num != 6 or num != 20:
    else:
        print ("Please input a valid die")
        #I would put a break statement here but it causes an error
pick_dice()
```

Should I just give up on the user input and try and build a GUI to where I just use a combobox within Tkinter for Dice selection, and buttons to call functions? As I aim to build a GUI for this program at some point. I'm really struggling to understand these basics.

I hope somebody out there is able to help me or point me in the right direction, thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is the *only* issue, but you shouldn't confuse equality (`==`) for identity (`is`) comparators. Instead do `if num == 6 or num == 20`

Comment: I think I may have over thought that one, I originally had ==, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your precise requirements are not clear to me but try:

```
from random import randint

def dice(num):
    d = randint(1, num)
    if d == 1:
        print("Uh Oh, Critical Fail")
    elif d == num:
        print("Congrats Critical Hit")
    else:
        print("You rolled a", d)

def pick_dice():
    while True:
        num = int(input("Please pick a valid die: 6 or 20: "))
        if num in (6, 20):
            dice(num)
            break
        else:
            print ("Please input a valid die")

pick_dice()
```

Notes:

1. `from random import randint` provides you with `randint`.  You don't need to also run `import random`.
2. In the original code, the line `num = int(input("Please pick a valid die: 6 or 20: "))` is evaluated once at the beginning of the run.   The statement `print (num)` prints `num` but does not cause the code to ask for input again.

   Similarly, `d6 = randint(1,2)` is evaluated only once.  You likely want to call `randint` again each time you need to roll a die.
3. As [Adam Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3058609/adam-smith) pointed out, `num is 6` returns True only if both `num` and `6` are stored in the same location in memory.  You want to check for equality instead: `num == 6`.  Also, if you want to check if `num` is either 6 or 20, then one can simply use `num in (6, 20)`.

Comment: Thank you for the response,
1.) Thank you for pointing out the redundant line.
2.) I thought having dice() referenced num and randint, which is then called by pick_dice() meant that I didn't have to worry about mentioning it again? Also Adding the num argument to the dice function causes me to receive a "TypeError: dice() missing 1 required positional argument: 'num'", hence why I left it out originally, as I could not work out where was the right place to add it in as I would either receive that or a num is not defined error, which didn't make sense as it was already defined?

Comment: 1) You're welcome.  2) In the way the python language works, `dice` does not invoke `randint`; it references numbers that are the result of previously having invoked `randint`. 3) In my version of the code, the expression `dice()` with no argument never appears and, hence, the error message that you see never occurs.